# Can warmachine Battle Engines gain stealth?

Tags: warmachine, hordes

Is it possible for a battle engine to gain stealth via a spell like Prowl while in an area that would grant concealment (like a forest)?

Given that forests and clouds don't block line of sight to a huge based model it seems weird that being in a forest with prowl would result in a stealthy battle engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concealment & Cover (pg 50) - This model never gains the DEF bonus from concealment or cover. It can get other effects (such as Prowl) though.

It's not explicitely said they can't get Stealth like Gargantuans, so they can.